# Install windows 8.1 on mac pro "we couldn't create a new partition..."

Tags: macos, windows-8.1, multi-boot, boot-camp

I hava a mac pro with 4 SATA hard drives a 2TB a 1TB and two 4TB.

The two 4TB are set up as a RAID and the 2TB has a clean install of OSX 10.11 on it.

I'm attempting to install Windows 8.1 onto the 1TB drive. I've created a bootable USB from the Windows 8.1 pro 64 bit iso that I downloaded from the [Microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows8ISO).

I used boot camp on a Macbook Pro (2014) to create the boot disk then I held down alt on the mac pro and selected the EFI boot (usb).

It boots up into the 8.1 setup fine and I select custom installation and select the 1TB disk. At this stage I have to format the disk to NTFS for setup to continue. Then when I check next I get a:

> We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup Log files

I ought to add that I've tried wiping the disk that I want to use using DISKPART (and also using the delete button on the setup). This allows me to progress to the next screen (loading windows files) but then I get:

> Windows could not prepare the computer to boot into the next phase of installation. To install Windows, restart the installation

Or sometimes I get an error code:

> 0x00000....5

I believe this is an "empty disk" error but I'm not sure.

Any help or point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I have also tried all this booting from iso burned to DVD.

Comment: I'm tempted to say, a cheese-grater Mac Pro can't do it from USB, needs to be DVD [but I'm not certain enough to post as an answer] Also not sure if that machine can use EFI/GPT boot for Windows. I have mine as MBR, though it's too many years since I actually first did it to recall how. The one I have now is a WinClone migrate from my last Pro.

Comment: Could you elaborate on WinClone? I have a macbook pro with a windows partition existing.

Comment: It's not cheap, & it's a one-trick pony, but essentially I just used it to copy a bootcamp install to another drive, which I put in a different machine. It worked. http://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone I managed to get away with the Basic version to do that.

Comment: Ahh yea I'm not a fan of paying for that. I'm looking at creating a disk image from the bootcamp partition, and copying that over. Not sure if it'll work though.

Comment: Any more ideas? I'm still struggling.

Comment: I have to admit, I tried a lot of alternative online help guides before giving up & using WinClone. Having said that, I was at least migrating a supported OS, I've never gone any higher than Win7 as a Bootcamp, though I have 10 in Parallels.